# Ghosted computer start button not working

Tags: windows-7, start-menu, norton-ghost

I ghosted a windows 7 pro x86 Optiplex 390 and now the dang start button doesn't work.  It recognizes when you hover over it but when you click...nothing.  I ran sfc /scannow and it finds errors but it says it cant repair them (same thing in safe mode).  Other than this one issue, the computer is working flawlessly.  I've googled the crap out of this problem with no avail.  I've run a chkdsk /f /r same results, does anyone have any idea why this might happen?

Thanks
msindle

Comment: UPDATE: it appears that when i click on it, the click never "releases".  It still shows that my mouse is hovering over it without my mouse actually hovering.

Comment: Have you tried a different mouse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to run a repair on the computer and that finally fixed it.